# Why does an RGBA bitmap require a 3x3 array to store 1 pixel and how can this be avoided?

Tags: java, opencv, bitmap, android

I have a 1x1 jpg image that consists of a single red colour.

I create a bitmap from the drawable image (Android) in this way:

```
Bitmap bitmap_image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.onebyonered);
```

However, calling `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on the bitmap outputs 3, 3.

I then convert the bitmap to a OpenCV matrix:

```
Mat matrix = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_64FC1);
// System.out.println(matrix);
Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap_image, matrix);
// System.out.println(matrix);
System.out.println(matrix.dump());
```

The first print statement returns `Mat [ 1*1*CV_64FC1, ...`, the second print statement returns `Mat [ 3*3*CV_8UC4, ...` and the matrix dump (converting to string) shows:

```
[255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255;
255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255;
255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255]
```

Grayscaling it using:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(matrix, matrix, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
```

Produces a 3x3x1 instead of the 1x1x1 expected:

```
[ 76,  76,  76;
  76,  76,  76;
  76,  76,  76]
```

Given the height and width mentioned above and assuming the dump is supposed to be in an RGBA format - why are 9 different values needed to represent a 1 pixel single colour image? And how can I change this 3x3x1 into the 1x1x1 that I want [76]? Ideally whatever conversion technique I use should be reversible or I'm able to display the bitmap image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` returning 3x3 because of the system is scaling your image as per device density so it's returning the wrong size. Put image in `assets` and load from there of or put it inside `drawable-nodpi` folder.

Comment: Fixed my problem my moving the jpg into a `drawable-nodpi` folder after creating it first. Thank you!